# Xamarin.Forms: Get all cells/items of a listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to make some changes to all of the cells shown in the [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/). Therefore I want to get all cells or items. E.g.

```
this.listView.ItemSource.Items
```

*Items* in the above code doesn't exist. Furthermore I didn't found any options on `ListView` or `ItemSource`, which could do this. Is it possible to get all cells/items? If not what other options do I have to change the appearence of the cells after they were loaded? E.g. for changing text or layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, you don't touch your cells directly. Instead, you try to do everything via data binding if it is possible.

Let's use the following Page defined in XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App6.Page1">
  <ListView x:Name="myList"
            BackgroundColor="Gray"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            RowHeight="-1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        Padding="15, 10, 10, 10"
                        BackgroundColor="White">

              <Label  Text="{Binding Title}"
                      FontSize="18"
                      TextColor="Black"
                      VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

In your Page, you set your ViewModel as BindingContext.

```cs
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new Page1ViewModel();
    }
}
```

And your ViewModel contains your Items `MyItems` in an ObservableCollection, which means that your view updates, if you add or remove Items. This property is bound as ItemsSource of you List (see XAML: `ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"`).

```cs
class Page1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Title = "Test" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Title = "Test2" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Title = "Test3" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Title = "Test4" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyItem { Title = "Test5" });
    }

    public void ChangeItem()
    {
        MyItems[1].Title = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

For each Item, you have an object that represents the data of **one** cell. The type of this item implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That means, that it notifies which property has been changed. The data binding mechanism registers to this event and will update the view, when it is raised.

```cs
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // Notify, that Title has been changed
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If you now change one of the items, e.g. by calling `ChangeItem()`. Then the Label of the second cell will update to `"Hello World"`, because it is bound to Title (see XAML `Text="{Binding Title}"`).

The general idea behind all this is called MvvM pattern, where you want to separate your view from the view logic and the model (data/services, ...).

Comment: I guess this answer helped the person who asked the question, but in my case the content of the cell has changed, which then affects its height. In iOS, the height doesn't appear to automatically grow, so the new words in the cell overlap the words in the next cell. I'd like to use Cell.ForceUpdateSize on the cell I just changed, but it looks to me like I need to get the actual cell objects to do that.

Answer (score 19):

I am probably late to the party, but here's another approach using System.Reflection. Anyways, I'd suggest using it only in cases where databinding isn't possible and as a last resort option.

For a given ListView

```xaml
<ListView x:Name="connectionsListView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemSelected="OnConnectionSelect">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="40">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <customs:MyViewClass Grid.Column="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <ContentView />
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

You can crawl through the ListView by grabbing the "TemplatedItems" property,
casting it to `ITemplatedItemsList<Cell>` and iterating through your (View)cells.

```cs
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pInfos = (connectionsListView as ItemsView<Cell>).GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
var templatedItems = pInfos.FirstOrDefault(info => info.Name == "TemplatedItems");
if (templatedItems != null)
{
  var cells = templatedItems.GetValue(connectionsListView);
    foreach (ViewCell cell in cells as Xamarin.Forms.ITemplatedItemsList<Xamarin.Forms.Cell>)
    {
        if (cell.BindingContext != null && cell.BindingContext is MyModelClass)
        {
            MyViewClass target = (cell.View as Grid).Children.OfType<MyViewClass>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (target != null)
            {
               //do whatever you want to do with your item... 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Since it was asked, if (cell.BindingContext != null && cell.BindingContext is MyModelClass) is basically a safeguard to prevent access to non-existing views, for instance if the ListView hasn't been populated yet.

If a check for the BindingContext being a particular model class isn't necessary, it would be sufficient to reduce the line to

```
if (cell.BindingContext != null)
```

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, what is MyViewClass actually referring to?

Comment: if I'm not guessed it wrong, Label / Switch / Button for example.

Comment: Yes, MyViewClass is the placeholder for whatever class you have added to your list and want to look for now.

Comment: I like this approach, the only problem ive came accross so far was when using a grouped listview. "cells" would only hold the group headers. Still pretty neat

Comment: @MarkusMichel, is it possible to have the ViewCell's height? It seems it is always -1

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro: That depends on the time when you are doing the iteration of your views. If you do it from within the constructor, the layout engine hasn't yet determined the actual height of the element.

If that is important for you to know, then you should consider iterating through your viewcells from within your contentpage's OnAppearing() method.

Comment: I don't know if it's a "timing" problem… I check the height when OnAppearing is done but it's always -1. BTW, I have found another method. Thanks