# Xamarin.Forms FindByName() always returns null

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms ListView with an ItemTemplate. The ItemTemplate contains an entry control named "myEntry". Each time an item is selected, I want to set focus to the entry control. In my xaml.cs ListView_ItemSelected event the listView.FindByName("myEntry") Method always returns null:

```
private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var lv = sender as ListView;
  if (lv != null)
  {
    var entry = lv.FindByName<Entry>("myEntry");
    if (entry != null)
      entry.Focus();
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelListe}"
            Header=""
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
            ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Grid Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="{Binding Bezeichnung}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ArtikelNr}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding KatalogNr}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Lagerplatz}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Mengeneinheit}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Sollbestand}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="myEntry" Grid.Column="6" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding AktuellerBestand}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding Kommentar}"/>
          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

I also tried to find other Controls from my xaml, but it's always null.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: @Mirja You always have one entry control regardless how many listitems you have?

Comment: One entry control per listitem

Comment: Basically you are assigning every item an entry control with the same name.

Comment: Yes, but the function does not seem to work anyway. I also tryed to find controls by name, which are not in a template. Like a simple named label in a stacklayout.

Answer (score 7):

WARNING: you shouldn't use `FindByName<>` in any of your code. And what you're trying to do would be done using Binding. But I'm going to answer anyway.

`myEntry` is part of the template for the cell of your ListView. Trying to find `lv.FindByName<Entry>("myEntry")` returns null, because the other alternative would be returning ALL `myEntry` of all Cells.

Why does it returns `null` ? Because thy are in different `NameScope`s. The Xaml parser creates one `NameScope` per Xaml root object in your file, and then different NameScopes for DataTemplates.

If you want to focus the `myEntry` of the active Cell. You would have to find the selected Cell, and then use FindByName on the cell.

But there's no easy way, in a templated control, to get a hook on the actual cell. That's why I started this answer with a warning. Read it again.

Comment: But returning all myEntry would help me more, because then I could pick the correct one by the selected index of the listview or not?

Answer (score 0):

If there *really* is no other way, you can traverse the visual tree with reflection.
I've described the way in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849187/xamarin-forms-get-all-cells-items-of-a-listview/47411840#47411840) some time ago.

Basically you only need to adapt the code to work with your layout. Fortunately you just have one entry view per cell, so as soon has you get an entry object, you simply have to check if it is the droid you were looking for.

Comment: This could be just a comment not an answer.