# c# listview add 2nd column row data

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

So I have a voteTotal variable that will count total of 7 states electoral votes.  However, the numbers are on different rows in the 2nd column but I'm not sure how I can add the electoral votes that are in the 2nd column.  First column is the state name and second column is the electoral votes total.

I don't really know how to call the rows so I am having trouble to add up the correct rows 2- 8 on the same column 2 of every row.

```
int voteTotal = 0;
int stateNumOne = 0;
int stateNumTwo = 0;
int stateNumThree = 0;
int stateNumFour = 0;
int stateNumFive = 0;
int stateNumSix = 0;
int stateNumSeven = 0;

if (votesListView.Items.Count < 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("List View can not be empty.");
}
if (votesListView.Items[0].SubItems[1] != null)
{
    stateNumOne = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text);
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}
if (votesListView.Items[1].SubItems[1] != null)
{
    stateNumTwo = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[1].SubItems[1].Text);
    MessageBox.Show("2");
}
else if (votesListView.Items[2].SubItems[1] != null)
{
    stateNumThree = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[2].SubItems[1].Text);
}

/*
stateNumSix = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[6].SubItems[
stateNumFour = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[4].SubItems[1].Text);
stateNumFive = int.Parse(votesListVie1].Text);
stateNumSeven = int.Parse(votesListView.Items[7].SubItems[1].Text);
*/

voteTotal = stateNumOne + stateNumTwo + stateNumThree + stateNumFour + stateNumFive + stateNumSix + stateNumSeven;
totalLabel.Text = voteTotal.ToString();
totalVotesLabel.Visible = true;
totalLabel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Yopu should [edit] your question to add a tag indicating the platform you are using because there is a `ListView` on each one of them and we really dont like guessing.

Comment: you mean like add visual studio?

Comment: No. Visual Studio is a development environment, not a platform. From the code you posted it looks like the platform you are using might be Xamarin.something.

Comment: I think it is by default Xamarin because I just downloaded visual studio 2017 and that was it.   From google it says "Visual Studio 2017 enables you to build native Android apps using Xamarin and C# or using Java/C++, and hybrid Android apps using Apache Cordova 6.3.1 and JavaScript and TypeScript"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but the first answer given to this post [Xamarin.Forms: Get all cells/items of a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849187/xamarin-forms-get-all-cells-items-of-a-listview) sounds like what you should be doing.

You should be using data binding and using that to fetch data. You should not be touching the cells/items directly.

But then again, your question itself is a bit vague. I hope it helps.

Comment: This wasn't helpful but thanks for trying.  So below is an example of my rows/columns in my listview.  What I am trying to do is add the electoral votes up in my list view which starts on the 2nd row and 2nd column and goes up.

State Name ,  Electoral Votes
Oregon                        7
Washington                 8
California                   55

Comment: Would that not be fixed with data binding though? All you do then edit the variable a variable, and since the cell value is bound to it, it will change as the variable changes.

Comment: Well the problem I am having is that I know how to retrieve the first row but I don't think my code is right to retrieve the second row.  When I look at your example you shown me I get confused because I can't visually see how the codes will create the listview.  In my listview there are 2 columns in every row and I need only the 2nd column of every row and add them.  In the examples I'm not sure if it is all in one row with multiple columns or if they are all in multiple rows if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried to simply get the count of items, then loop through your listview, adding every value you get from the second column based on your loop index? It seems like that would be much simpler than doing it one by one

Comment: oh I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following screenshot?
[image]

Here is layout.

```
  <ListView  x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModels} ">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding State}"
                            />
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Votes}"

                           />
                    </Grid>


                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is background code.

```
  BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
```

Here is code for `MyViewModel`

```
 class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyModels = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "State Name", Votes = "Electoral Votes" 
        });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "Oregon ", Votes = "7" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "Washington", Votes = "8" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "California", Votes = "55" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "lost1", Votes = "22" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "lost2", Votes = "24" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "lost3", Votes = "25" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "lost4", Votes = "26" });
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = "lost5", Votes = "27" });

        int sumVotes = 0;
        for (int i=1;i<MyModels.Count;i++)
        {
            sumVotes+= Int32.Parse(MyModels[i].Votes);
        }
        MyModels.Add(new MyModel() { State = " ", Votes = 
        "sum"+sumVotes.ToString()});



    }
}
```

Here id code for `MyModel`

```
     public class MyModel
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Votes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int voteTotal = 0;
int secondcolumn = 1;

    enter code here

if (votesListView.Items.Count < 1)
    MessageBox.Show("List View can not be  empty.");
else
    {
    for(int spot = 0; spot < votesListView.Items.Count; spot++)
        {
        voteTotal += int.Parse(votesListView.Items[spot].SubItems[secondcolumn].Text);
        //This will pop up a MessageBox at each iteration of this for loop.
        //feel free to comment out the MessageBox if it doesn't work.
        //you can also print out the voteTotal after the for loop.
        MessageBox.Show(spot.ToString());
        }
    }
```